# TypeORM - PrimaryGeneratedColumn increment strategy vs default strategy

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

In TypeORM, what is the difference between

```
PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
```

and

```
PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
```

I tried running both in Postgres and Nest.js and I see no difference when I do

```
PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment') id: number
```

PG version:
psql (13.2 (Ubuntu 13.2-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-1.pgdg20.04+1))

Comment: check `typeorm/src/decorator/columns/PrimaryGeneratedColumn.ts`, you can see the default and diffrentd.

Comment: all its says is `Column decorator is used to mark a specific class property as a table column.` for every method. This doesn't tell me anything

Answer (score 1):

I think increment is just default strategy.

Comment: so why are there 2 then?